# Getting @rid while Update-Upsert in OrientDB without searching again

Tags: insert, orientdb, upsert

I am currently using OrientDB to build a graph model. I am using **PyOrient** to send commands for creating the nodes and edges.

Whenever I use INSERT command I get a list of things which includes @rid in return.

`result = db.command("INSERT INTO CNID SET connected_id {0}".format(somevalue))`

`print result`

OUTPUT: `{'@CNID':{'connected_id': '10000'},'version':1,'rid':'#12:1221'}`

However if I use the Update-Upsert command I only get one value as return which is not the @rid.

`result = db.command("UPDATE CNID SET connected_id={0} UPSERT WHERE connected_id={0}".format(cn_value))`
`print result`

OUTPUT: `1`

I want to know is it possible to get @rid as well while doing UPDATE-UPSERT operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following example in **PyOrient**:

**Structure:**

[image]

A useful method to retrieve the `@rid` from an `UPDATE / UPSERT` operation could be the usage of the `RETURN AFTER $current` syntax in your SQL command.

**PyOrient Code:**

```
import pyorient


db_name = 'Stack37308500'

print("Connecting to the server...")
client = pyorient.OrientDB("localhost",2424)
session_id = client.connect("root","root")
print("OK - sessionID: ",session_id,"\n")

if client.db_exists( db_name, pyorient.STORAGE_TYPE_PLOCAL ):
    client.db_open(db_name, "root", "root")
    result = client.command("UPDATE CNID SET connected_id = 20000 UPSERT RETURN AFTER $current.@rid WHERE connected_id = 20000")
    for idx, val in enumerate(result):
        print(val)

client.db_close()
```

By specifying `$current.@rid` you'll be able to retrieve the `@rid` of the resulting record (in this case a new record).

**Code Output:**

```
Connecting to the server...
OK - sessionID:  25 

##12:1
```

**Studio:**

[image]

You can also modify the query to retrieve the whole resulting record by use only `$current` without specifying `@rid` (in this case I updated the record `#12:1`).

**Query:**

```
UPDATE CNID SET connected_id = 30000 UPSERT RETURN AFTER $current WHERE connected_id = 20000
```

**Code Output:**

```
Connecting to the server...
OK - sessionID:  26 

{'@CNID':{'connected_id': 30000},'version':2,'rid':'#12:1'}
```

**Studio:**

[image]

Hope it helps